# call node function, from ejs form

Tags: node.js, forms, function, express, ejs

I'm making a node application where I need to call a function, written inside my app.js, and I need to call it from, a form, in a template, made with ejs. 
i'm using node.js, express.js and ejs.
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use ajax to interface with the server-side function:

```
$.get('/your_route', {data: 'goes here'}, function (res) {
    console.log('callback after your node function is done')
})
```

You might call the function from the template by:

```
<form class="ajax_caller" onsubmit="do_ajax_call()">form goes here</form>
```

However that is not considered a good practice. This is much better:

```
// click event
$(document).on('submit', 'form.ajax_caller', do_ajax_call)

function do_ajax_call (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $.get('/your_route', {data: 'goes here'}, function (res) {
        console.log('callback after your node function is done')
    })
}
```

Ofcourse you will have to set up a route in express:

```
app.get('/your_route', function (req, res) {
    finally_your_function()
    res.send('finished')
});
```

If you don't want to use ajax, you can just set the action of the form to your ajax route, however that will redirect user to the route so you will have to handle that.

Comment: Thx, that helped alot

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular HTML forms which submit their content to a certain URL on the server.

Example:

Add the form to HTML/EJS:

```
<form method="GET" action="/sampleUrl">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Add the route to your app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.get('/sampleUrl', function(req, res) {
  //Do something
});
```